# Create Nixie tube pin connector socket in eagle cad

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am unsure how to properly layout a socket for a nixie tube in eagle cad. I'm especially unsure how to match the exact dimensions and what tool in eagle to use to create a hole with copper on both sides to house the pin connector.

The socket I'm trying to layout is for the recreation of the z568m tube. The socket is specified here (http://docs.daliborfarny.com/documentation/tube-socket/) with dxf file which can be imported into eagle cad. The recommended pin connector is https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=H3161-01. The recommended hole diameter for the connector is, accoring to the socket spec, 1.95mm for ENIG surface finish, which my pcb manufacturer uses.

How would you create the socket? I started importing the dxf file onto the tNames layer. Then I created VIAs on the VIA layer with a drill diameter of 1.95mm and tried to match the positions of the imported dxf file by hand.

Anyways, this didn't feel like the proper way to do. Neither was I able to perfectly match the imported layout, nor am I sure whether using VIAs is the right choice. According to http://docs.daliborfarny.com/documentation/tube-socket/ the pin socket is pressed into the pcb and soldered from the bottom. Is that even possible with VIAs?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: First of all, are you doing this in the layout editor or the library editor? You should be using the library editor, and you should be using through-hole pads for the pins, not vias.

Comment: I simply created a new board. But thats a good hint to start right away in the library editor to make it reusable. Or are there any further advantages? Thanks for the tip with through-hole pads! Any other advice/tips/things I should look out for? Any tips how to match the dimensions?

Comment: Always create new components in the component library, regardless of the tool.  Eagle has a nice tutorial in their documentation.  Follow that, and use the *dimensioned drawing* from the manufacturer if it is available.  If not, use the physical part and a good pair of calipers to get the dimensions.

Comment: In this case, you have a drawing dimensioned in a polar coordinate system, so use your favorite method (I'd use an Excel spreadsheet or C program probably) to convert the pin locations to Cartesian coordinates in your measurement systems of choice, rounded to the resolution of your tool, to reduce the chance of any transcription errors. Double check for the pin locations being reasonable by printing out the locations, eyeballing it, checking a 1:1 print against the component itself  etc. Double check the hole diameters, that's where a lot of errors happen (usually too small-- a real pain).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great advice. Also just found out there is the possibility to change an elements position in its properties.

Comment: What I'm still struggling with is changing the size of the through hole pads. I cannot find any resource on the internet which explains it. I have different sized through hole pads in the eagle lib under "wirepad", e.g. "2,54/0,9 (Version 1) - THROUGH-HOLE PAD". According to some resources it should be possible to change the drill and pad size by using the "Change" tool. However that does not change anything. Does anyone know how to change these pads to the right dimension/drill diameter?